# Json unmarshal type model in golang

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a RESTful service that returns response similar to show below:

```
"Basket" : {
  "Count": 1,
  "Fruits": {[
    {
      "Name":"Mango", 
      "Season":"Summer"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Fig", 
      "Season":"Winter"}
  ]}
}
```

I am trying to create Go lang model to unmarshal the contents. Following is the code I have tried:

```
type Response struct {
    Count   int
    Fruits []Fruit
}

type Fruit struct {
    Name string
    Season string
}
```

But when I marshal the Response object in my test code I don't see similar json. (https://play.golang.org/p/EGKqfbwFvW)
Marshalled data always appears as :

```
{
  "Count":100,
  "Fruits":[
    {"Name":"Mango","Season":"Summer"},
    {"Name":"Fig","Season":"Winter"}
  ]
}
```

Notice the Fruits appearing as array **[]** and not **{[]}** in original json. How can I model structs in golang for this response?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Fruits needs to be either an array or a name: value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is totally correct and valid, but the JSON object is not. `"Fruits"` doesn't have name if it should be key value pair or it should be wrapped in `[]` not `{}`.

JSON obj should be formatted like this:

```
{
  "Basket" : {
    "Count": 1,
    "Fruits": [
      {
        "Name":"Mango", 
        "Season":"Summer"
      },
      {
        "Name":"Fig", 
        "Season":"Winter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And actually invalid json shouldn't work https://play.golang.org/p/yoW7t4NfI7

Comment: You are spot on, the JSON I am consuming comes from a 3rd party and is invalid. I switch to XML and my structure works perfectly (This is why I like Go, transition is just 2 line change). I also validated with json.RawMessage. Json is not supposed to have "[" after "{".

Answer (score 1):

I would make 'Baskets' a struct within 'Response', create a 'BasketsData' struct,  and give it all some labels.

```
type Fruit struct {
    Name   string `json:"Name"`
    Season string `json:"Season"`
}

type BasketData struct {
    Count  int     `json:"Count"`
    Fruits []Fruit `json:"Fruits"`
}

type Response struct {
    Basket BasketData `json:"Basket"`
}
```

This way you will get a top level JSON response when you marshall it.

```
fruitmania := []Fruit{{Name: "Mango", Season: "Summer"},
                       {Name: "Fig", Season: "Winter"}}
basket := Response{BasketData{Count: 100, Fruits: fruitmania}}

b, _ := json.Marshal(basket)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```

checkit-checkit out:
https://play.golang.org/p/TuUwBLs_Ql

Comment: This does not solve the issue of Fruits appearing as array **[]** and not **{[]}**. Output should have "Fruits":{[{"Name":"Mango","Season":"Summer"},{"Name":"Fig","Season":"Winter"}]}

Comment: @sukkad that's not valid JSON